# mac vist docker hadoop hdfs datanode failed

Tags: java, docker, hadoop, hdfs

I use local docker to run ubuntu container, and installed **hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.15.1** And expose `8020:8020 50072:50070`  to my macbook pro.
Now I try to use Java API to create a file and write something to save it to HDFS. Here is my code.

```
configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.set("dfs.replication", "1");
fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://hadoop0:8020"), configuration, "root");
fileSystem.mkdirs(new Path("/hdfsapi/test"));
FSDataOutputStream out = fileSystem.create(new Path("/hdfsapi/test/a.txt"));
out.writeUTF("hello world");
out.flush();
out.close();
```

But when I run this code, I'm getting these errors

```
[WARN ] method:org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.<clinit>(NativeCodeLoader.java:62)
Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[INFO ] method:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1781)
Exception in createBlockOutputStream
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/172.17.0.5:50010]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:2008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:790)
[WARN ] method:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1671)
Abandoning BP-172896758-172.17.0.5-1600359208346:blk_1073741837_1013
[WARN ] method:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1675)
Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.17.0.5:50010,DS-48b4e638-f814-4ac7-9aae-ea317b91ea5d,DISK]
[WARN ] method:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:912)
DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /hdfsapi/test/a.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:694)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2277)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2275)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:425)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1860)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:790)
---------tearDown--------



org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /hdfsapi/test/a.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:694)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2277)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2275)


    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:425)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1860)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:790)
```

Then I use

```
hadoop fs -text /hdfsapi/test/a.txt
```

...and find that the file has been created but "hello world" was not in file.

I think this maybe caused by my macbook pro, but don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I restart my docker hadoop, and see namenode logs. And I found these words.

```sh
2020-09-18 00:59:46,904 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockReportLeaseManager: Registered DN 40567cac-8c47-482e-bbde-4c8862d8b5a2 (172.17.0.5:50010).
```

So i think that maybe caused by i don't expose my 50010 port.